# Saving user to DB with user role (JAVA)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am starting my Java journey, and am working in STS, trying to save a new user to MySQL database, but it doesn't seem like anything is saving. Upon registering, the new user should be automatically given the role of USER, and then saved into the SQL database. When I run the application, it seems that everything runs fine, but when I try to create a new user, I get redirected back into the login page with nothing saved in the database.

Here are my files:

UserController:

```
package developer.andy.auth.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import developer.andy.auth.models.User;
import developer.andy.auth.services.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {
    
    private UserService userService;
    
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        return "register.jsp";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/process")
    public String process(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpSession session) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "register.jsp";
        }
        System.out.println("SAVED USER: "+ user);
        userService.saveWithUserRole(user);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login.jsp";
    }
    
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auth
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Web Config:

```
package developer.andy.auth.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    // Add BCrypt Bean
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder pwEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout().permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

User Model:

```
package developer.andy.auth.models;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String username;
    
    private String password;
    
    @Transient // allows us to have attributes that are not directly tied to the model
    private String confirm;
    
    @Column(updatable=false) // creates column in DB that cannot be edited
    private Date createdAt;
    
    private Date updatedAt;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List <Role> roles;
    
    public User() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirm() {
        return confirm;
    }

    public void setConfirm(String confirm) {
        this.confirm = confirm;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreated() {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }
    
    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }
    
}
```

Role Model:

```
package developer.andy.auth.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users; // points to User table
    
    public Role() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    
    
}
```

User Repo:

```
package developer.andy.auth.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import developer.andy.auth.models.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Role Repo:

```
package developer.andy.auth.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import developer.andy.auth.models.Role;

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, String> {
    List<Role> findAll();
    List<Role> findByName(String name);
}
```

User service:

```
package developer.andy.auth.services;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import developer.andy.auth.models.User;
import developer.andy.auth.repositories.RoleRepository;
import developer.andy.auth.repositories.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {
    
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    private RoleRepository roleRepo;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder pwEncoder;
    
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepo, RoleRepository roleRepo, BCryptPasswordEncoder pwEncoder) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
        this.roleRepo = roleRepo;
        this.pwEncoder = pwEncoder;
    }
    
    // save with user role
    public void saveWithUserRole(User user) {
        user.setPassword(pwEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(roleRepo.findByName("ROLE_USER"));
        System.out.println("New User: " + user);
        userRepo.save(user);
    }
    
    // save with admin role
    public void saveWithAdminRole(User user) {
        user.setPassword(pwEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(roleRepo.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        System.out.println("New Admin: " + user);
        userRepo.save(user);
    }
    
    // find user by username
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }
    
}
```

register.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Register!</h1>
    
    <p><form:errors path="user.*"/></p>
    
    <form:form method="POST" action="/process" modelAttribute="user">
        <p>
            <form:label path="username">Username:</form:label>
            <form:input path="username"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <form:label path="password">Password:</form:label>
            <form:password path="password"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <form:label path="confirm">Confirm:</form:label>
            <form:password path="confirm"/>
        </p>
<!--         We do not need a csrf token in register bc jstl has already included them for us -->
        <input type="submit" value="Register!"/>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to check the models, modified the POST URL, and included some console logs to find the issues, but even upon doing so, it doesn't seem to log any errors or data on to the console. This is what gets outputted into the console:

```
2022-11-10 22:20:18.829  INFO 6389 --- [           main] developer.andy.auth.AuthApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-11-10 22:20:19.915  INFO 6389 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-11-10 22:20:19.997  INFO 6389 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 70 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-11-10 22:20:20.974  INFO 6389 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-11-10 22:20:20.986  INFO 6389 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-11-10 22:20:20.987  INFO 6389 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2022-11-10 22:20:21.323  INFO 6389 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2022-11-10 22:20:21.337  INFO 6389 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-11-10 22:20:21.337  INFO 6389 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2405 ms
2022-11-10 22:20:21.552  INFO 6389 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-11-10 22:20:21.607  INFO 6389 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
2022-11-10 22:20:21.806  INFO 6389 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-11-10 22:20:21.926  INFO 6389 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-11-10 22:20:22.336  INFO 6389 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-11-10 22:20:22.368  INFO 6389 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-11-10 22:20:23.373  INFO 6389 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-11-10 22:20:23.383  INFO 6389 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-11-10 22:20:23.869  WARN 6389 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 


2022-11-10 22:20:24.136  INFO 6389 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@726e29d, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@a1e578f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@40239b34, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@811d8d6, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@50841932, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3c468360, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@72b6fa98, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1c966488, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@45f6181a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@707b38a1, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6dcc7696, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3bf52f8f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6eae3730]
2022-11-10 22:20:24.197  WARN 6389 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-11-10 22:20:24.775  INFO 6389 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-11-10 22:20:24.789  INFO 6389 --- [           main] developer.andy.auth.AuthApplication      : Started AuthApplication in 6.691 seconds (JVM running for 8.204)
2022-11-10 22:20:36.705  INFO 6389 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-10 22:20:36.705  INFO 6389 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-10 22:20:36.706  INFO 6389 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your browser console say when you submit the form?

Comment: You are going to post to `form method="POST" action="/process" ` - where is this code? Have you put debugging statements in this code? What happens here?

Comment: Hi @ScaryWombat my apologies, I didn't realize I did not add in my controller file . I have amended it to the top of the post if you want to take a look

Comment: Hello @tgdavies When I submit the form, nothing prints to the web console

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `process` and make sure it is doing what you expect.

Comment: Is `System.out.println("New User: " + user);` being printed out?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions! I am going to try to tinker with all your recommendations now and provide an update shortly! :)

Comment: @ScaryWombat it is not

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out why I was not able to save the data to the DB. It seems that I specified the incorrect data types in the roleRepo.

I changed <Role, String> to <Role, Long> to reference the ID and now it works fine! Thank you for all your help everyone!

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Long> {
    List<Role> findAll();

    List<Role> findByName(String name);
    
}
```